# Different result AzureDevops RestApi Interactive vs Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When I type in a command to retrieve all queries in a specific project, i.e.:
[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries?$depth=4&api-version=7.1-preview.2](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/queries?$depth=4&api-version=7.1-preview.2)
I get a result that shows both topfolders "My Queries"and "Shared Queries" in Json format ánd all the queries that resides iin these folders.
However, when is paste the same uri in a powershell script, it only will give me the two topfolders; hence I'm not able to search the 'leaves'.

Powershell:

```
$user              = "my patcode"
$base64AuthInfo    = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f   $user,$token)))
$posturl= "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries?$depth=2&api-version=7.1-preview.2"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=  ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}|convertto-json
```

Comment: There may be Java Scripts that aren't running (or running after the response is sent).  You also may need to add the HTTP Header User-Agent to get all the results.

Comment: I run powershell in ISE, so I don't think this Java Script running is causing troubles.

Comment: ISE has nothing to do with the HTTP Server.  ISE is on client.  The JAVA Scripts are running on Server.  When you use a webpage to connect to a URL often you will see the Webpage updating after you connect.  That is the Java Script running.  What is being returned to the Invoke-RestMethod is the initial view of the webpage and not including the updates from the Java Script.

Comment: Here is PS code that allows the Java Script to run.  It uses a WebBrowser instead of Invoke-RestMethod  https://gist.github.com/omidkrad/fbb4bfb3b1f5b83c9898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points here:

1. Use '/queries?`$depth' in URL because poweshell tries to use $depth variable.
2. Play with Depth parameter in convetto-json

   ```
   $posturl= "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries?`$depth=2&api-version=7.1-preview.2"

   Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
   ```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I already played with the depth values. This won't give me the result either.

Comment: @user23314406 the main issue is $depth in the URL... use `$depth

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help.

Comment: @user23314406 it should work. I added execution to my answer.

Comment: Shame on me. You are absolutely right! I overlooked the depth in the commandline "ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100". This helps really a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same with you, please fix with below steps:

1. Use '/queries?`$depth' in URL because poweshell tries to use $depth variable.
2. Use `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet instead of `Invoke-RestMethod`.As the Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet in PowerShell automatically converts JSON content to a PowerShell object, which could exclude the `children`(query details) from the output.

Script as below:

```
$token              = "PAT"

$base64AuthInfo    = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f   $user,$token)))

$headers = @{
   Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
}

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/wit/queries?`$depth=2&api-version=7.1-preview.2" -Headers $headers

$response.Content
```

Query details in response:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that might help. A quick investigation showed that indeed it showed "children", like your response-screenshot.